# How can I attach modern spindles to these treads?

Tags: stairs

We recently bought a terraced house in the North of England (built in 1880). Its three stories, and its beautiful curved bannister that would have run continuously from ground to second floor had been ripped out some time in the past and had been replaced by a horrible banister made from planks of wood. We'd like to put a bannister back in that is in keeping, however it looks like the price of a curved bannister means it is not an option, so we'll have to settle for straight sections between Newell posts.

All the modern spindles I can find for sale have square bases, but the holes that are present from the original spindles are circular. **My question is how can we fit them? Do we need to buy square-based spindles and use a lathe to shape them for the holes? Is there some other way to do it?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Google showed quite a few round and square types with round pegs on the bottom to fit into round holes.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can turn pegs onto each spindle to match the holes or you can drill into each spindle and glue a suitable diameter dowel into place.

I would be making a jig and drilling.

Answer (score 1):

You could buy round top spindles & turn them over.
Who would ever know?

https://www.stairbits.com/product/round-top-spindles/

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There should be options to find balusters with a turned pin bottom. In some cases, even if the baluster is only available with a square bottom or without a pin, there are some suppliers that will have a small drilled hole in which a "pin adapter" will fit into, so it will have what is needed to fit your need.

Photo courtesyStairpartsusa.com
[image]

Another option would be to fill the hole with small cut pieces of 19mm?? (3/4" sorry a yank here) wood dowel and that will allow you to use [baluster dowel screws](https://stairpartsusa.com/collections/hardware-misc/products/c1107) to secure the balusters in place.